# issue in numeric validation javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I am using a phone number field in my web page. I need to check whether the value entered in that field should numeric and 10 digit number. For that i used the following code.

```
var phonead;
function checkphonead(int){
   var filter=/^[0-9]{10}$/;
   if (filter.test(int)) {
      phonead = true;
   }
   else {
      phonead = false;
   }
   return phonead;
}

if(document.admission_form.phone.value=='') {
   alert("Please enter your phone number");
   document.getElementById('phone').focus();
   return false; 
}


if(checkphonead(document.getElementById('phone').value) == false) {
   alert("Please enter a 10 digit phone number!");
   document.getElementById('phone').focus();
   return false;
}
```

If I submit the form with any phone number it just saved as `2147483647` in the database. If I remove the above script, the correct phone number value has saved in the database. I couldn't trace why it happens. Any suggestion?

Comment: A little indentation goes a long way.

Comment: 2147483647 isn't some default value somewhere or something? Also I would be tempted to put some {} between `if (filter.test(int))
phonead=true
else
`

Comment: You dropped these: `;;;;;;;;`

Comment: The value 2147483647 is significant in that it's 2^31 - 1, or the largest value a signed 32-bit integer can hold. If you're trying to convert a 10 digit number into a 32-bit number somewhere in your backend, that could be an issue for some values.

Comment: As FatalError said, you shouldn't be storing a phone number as an integer. A numerical value for a phone number is insignificant. It's likely that if you used an integer in your mySql database, that that's the source of the problem.

Comment: Just an aside, you could make your `checkphonead()` function much simpler because it only needs a single line of code: `return phonead = /^[0-9]{10}$/.test(int);` - this assigns a value to `phonead` and returns that same value all at once. (I'm not sure what the `phonead` variable is used for outside that function; if it's not used then you don't need the variable and the function can just say `return /^[0-9]{10}$/.test(int);`)

Comment: @FatalError - You're probably onto something there, but why then if the above script is removed would the value be stored correctly like the OP said?

Comment: @nnnnnn Perhaps the OP happened to use a different test case? Some 10 digit numbers can fit in a 32-bit int, some can't. Other than that, I've no idea.

Answer (score -1):

int is a key word, try passing different parameter name and try!

updated:

the issue is not with javascript... but in database structure declaration.. for phone number structure in DB please use bigint if in mysql ot leave it as a text field itself. It should work fine then !!

Comment: This is javascript. int is not a reserved word. Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: oh BAD BAD! my apology friends!! @designersvsoft the issue is not with javascript... but in database structure declaration.. for phone number structure in DB please use bigint if in mysql ot leave it as a text field itself. It should work fine then !!!